# evaluate a function binds to current namespace using read-string

Tags: clojure

I struggle to evaluate a string contains a function call. The function is defined in the same namespace where the evaluation happens. Everything works well if a symbol comes from a library referring inside `ns` body like: `(ns myname.myapp (:require [clj-time.core]))`.

My goal is to load a file (edn format) that interops with custom symbols. Here is a bare minimum setup to reproduce the issue:

```
(ns myname.myapp
  (:import [java.time Instant])
  (:gen-class))

(defn time-now []
  (->
   (Instant/now)
   (.toString)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (prn (eval (read-string "{:now (time-now)}"))))
```

If I evaluate sexp by sexp inside the source file buffer everything ok, but cli execution `clj -m myname/myapp` leads to `Unable to resolve symbol: time-now in this context`. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that when the code is evaluating inside IDE/text editor the current namespace is pointing to the last evaluated namespace, and in the example above it is `myname.myapp`, so that's why the code works.

But with the complied jar or cli module running, the active namespace has another name (ether `clojure.core` or `user`). The solution is to rebind the namespace when the evaluation is taking place:

```
(ns myname.myapp
  (:import [java.time Instant])
  (:gen-class))

(defn time-now []
  (->
   (Instant/now)
   (.toString)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (binding [*ns* (find-ns 'myname.myapp)]
    (prn (eval (read-string "{:now (time-now)}")))))
```